# can't install hardly anything...winbind unstable

Tags: dpkg

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
winbind is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2,511 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: error processing winbind (--configure):
 Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 winbind
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This is the general idea anytime I try to do anything with winbind.

Comment: Could you mention how did you fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Running:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install winbind
```

Reference: [AptGet manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto)

Comment: I think it's `sudo apt-get install --reinstall winbind`

Comment: @AdityaPatil I tried with Gedit in my computer and both have worked.